# Craft Commerce payment gateway: general info requested

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, payment, tax

one of our clients requested us to create a global webshop for their business. We have little experience with webshops and as we are avid fans of Craft, we'd like to start on this project with Craft Commerce.

It would be built with Commerce 1.x as their current site is based on Craft 2 and an update to Craft 3 is not possible at the moment.

My questions are a bit broad and is based on our little experience we have with Magento:

**how far does Craft Commerce go when a user puts an order?**
- The user buys something on the website
- The order is sent to the Payment gateway
- When the payment is processed, the gateway sends a confirmation back.
- **What does Craft do next? Does it automatically set a new order status "paid"? It creates an order, but does it handle cancelations or order credit notes?**
Or does Craft Commerce quits when the order is created?

Magento has some sort of built-in bookkeeping, but how far does Craft go?

**What gateway is best for global/international payments?**

Answer (score 2):

**How far does Craft Commerce go when a user puts an order?**

When an order is paid in full it is marked as complete and gets a default order status that you can configure, after that a store admin would move the order to another status.

An order can also be completed if the payment gateway 'authorizes' the full amount of the order, allowing a store admin to 'capture' that payment at a later time.

**But does it handle cancelations or order credit notes?**

Cancellations of an order are a manual process. You would usually perform these steps:

- Refund the transaction
- Change the order status to a status you set up like 'cancelled'.
- Have an email automatically go to the customer notifying them of the cancellation based on the order status.

**Or does Craft Commerce quits when the order is created?**

Not sure what you mean here, but you can manage the order in the CP after the order is completed.

**Magento has some sort of built-in bookkeeping, but how far does Craft go?**

Craft Commerce does not keep any type of accounting ledger, it simply allows you to manage order and take payments on those orders. Most developer build a custom sql query to export data to their accounting system.

**What gateway is best for global/international payments?**

Craft Commerce allows a single store with a single currency for all prices entered into that store for products / discounts / taxes etc.

You can have your products be manually translated for other regions since they are multi-locale aware.

Craft Commerce does have the ability to accept payment in currencies other than your primary currency so that your customer gets charged in a currency they expect to show up on their credit card statement - but you control the conversion ratio yourself.

It would be best to find the right payment gateway to use that supports the currencies/global regions for payments and then find out the level of support for that gateway in Craft Commerce. We always suggest Stripe.

Hope that helps.